# Keeping Encoding when Reading Image File

Tags: java, input, encoding, tiff

I'm am currently reading through a file which contains meta-data and a tiff image like so:

```
private String readFile( String file ) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    int size = (int) file.length();     
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new   FileInputStream(file));
    buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    buf.close();
    ...
}
```

I parse the meta-data + image content, then I try to output the tiff like this, where img is a String:

```
    writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( "img.tiff"));
    writer.write(img);
    writer.close();
```

Why is the encoding being lost of the tiff image file?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be reading a binary file into a `String`.

Comment: How would I go about parsing the meta-data + image then?

Comment: I don't know which metadata it is (is it text?), but read the content as a `byte[]`.

Comment: The meta-data is regular text

Comment: Sortirios, I've read the input of the file as a byte array and that reads it properly, but I would like to manipulate the string.  Do you know how to properly convert a byte-array to a string with keeping the encoding?

Comment: I don't know the format of a `tiff` file, but if you can find out which offset the text is at, you can convert a number X of bytes from the `byte[]` to a String and keep the rest as binary.

Comment: Reading a binary Format using a `FileReader` is questionable but may make sense. Writing those character sequences back and expecting the result to be equal to the original binary again, though, is a no-go. Using a `Reader` generally is destructive to non-text files.

Comment: As others have pointed out, do not treat binary data as a `String`. It might work in special cases, but it really is not the intended use, and will cause problems. For reading images and image metadata, use ImageIO. If you only want meta data, you could use [metadata-extractor](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/) or similar. As a side note: Your `readFile` code is flawed, as `buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)` in't guaranteed to read a specific number of bytes, you have to check the return value, and read in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to rewrite the file?
If the answer is "I'm trying to alter some metadata within the file." I strongly suggest that you use a set of tools that are specifically geared towards working with TIFF metadata, especially if you intend to manipulate/alter than metadata as there are several special case data elements in TIFF files that really don't like being moved around blithely.

My day-to-day job involves understanding the TIFF spec, so I always get a little antsy when I see people mucking around with the internals of TIFFs without first consulting the spec or being concerned with some of the bizarre special cases that exist in the wild that now need to be handled because of *someone else* who didn't fully grok the spec and created a commercial product that generated thousands of these beasts (I'm looking at *you* Microsoft for making "old style JPEG compression" TIFFs, but I've also seen a Java product that defined a type of image that used floating point numbers for the component values without bothering to (1) normalize them as the spec would have you do or (2) have a standard for defining what the expected min and max of the component values would be).

In [my code base](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/joltimage/) (and this is a commercial product), you can do your work like this:

```
TiffFile myTiff = new TiffFile();
myTiff.read(someImageInputStream);

for (TiffDirectory dir : myTiff.getImages())
{
    // a TiffDirectory contains a collection of TiffTag objects, from which the
    // metadata for each image in the document can be read/edited
    // TiffTag definitions can be found [here][2].
}
myTiff.save(someImageOutputStream); // writes the whole TIFF back
```

and in general, we've found that it's really advanced customers who want to do this.  For the most part, we find that customers are more concerned with higher-level operations like combining TIFF files into a single document or extracting out pages, for which we have a different API which is much lighter weight and doesn't require you to know the TIFF specification (as it should be).

Comment: It's because the TIFF image is inside a COF file, which is just a collection of meta-data and their corresponding tiff images.  I wouldn't be altering the data; I would be splicing the tiff's and not messing with the actual image.

Comment: Splicing?  Do you mean extracting?  If so, make a stream on top of the binary data and just copy it where you want it to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the encoding in your writer.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder%29

Wrap your stream:

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

For images you should look into the ImageIO package.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageWriter%28javax.imageio.ImageReader%29

Comment: Would I have to specify the encoding on the readfile too?  No luck with the encoding.

Comment: Wrapping it in UTF-8 didn't help.  I'll take a look at ImageIO